# How do we use command lines or Script (msbuild) to build Cordova Project created with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I use Visual Studio to create Cordova projects. I need to build Cordova projects using msbuild and buildbot via script for my project but I can find only information about how VS combine with Cordova CLI to build multi device hybrid application.

Answer (score 2):

Our Visual Studio team has published some tutorials for building Cordova projects using Team Foundation Server 2013 and MSBuild. There may be some pointers in here you could adapt for your needs, if you still need help.

https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/1d1c0872ac3b2f22301138915efcfa1dd87caea8/tutorial-team-build/TFS2013.md

Are there specific issues you encountered when trying to run an msbuild command from the command line to build a .jsproj project?

- Jordan, Microsoft Visual Studio team